# Rails 4 with Bootstrap - configuration and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I am going crazy.

I am trying to use Bootstrap js tabs in my rails 4 app. It is sending me spare.

At the moment, I have copied the boot snip example into my code. It works absolutely fine.

I have also used a copy of that code to make my actual code (also below). The tabs don't work in my version. Clicking on them doesn't do anything. The key changes between my version and the boot snip version are:

1. my version is in containerfluid -v- boot snip is in container
2. my version has rendered partials in the tab panels -v- boot snip has lorem ipsum, however when I try copying text from my partials into the tab panel, I get the same problem.
3. I have css styling in my partials.

bootsnip example:

```
<div class="containerfluid" style="margin-top:50px">


    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <!-- Nav tabs --><div class="card">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
                                    </div>
</div>
                                </div>
    </div>
```

My attempt at copy /paste/change html in boot snip example:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <!-- Nav tabs --><div class="card">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#terms" aria-controls="terms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Terms</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#privacy" aria-controls="privacy" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#licence" aria-controls="licence" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Licence</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#trust" aria-controls="trust" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Trust</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#reliance" aria-controls="reliance" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Reliance</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#pricing" aria-controls="pricing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pricing</a></li>

                </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>            


            <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="terms">
                    <%= render 'pages/legalpolicies/terms' %>
                </div>

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="privacy">
                    <%= render 'pages/legalpolicies/privacy' %>
                </div>

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="licence">
                    <%= render 'pages/legalpolicies/licence' %>
                </div>


                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="trust">
                    <%= render 'pages/legalpolicies/trust' %>
                </div>

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="reliance">
                    <%= render 'pages/legalpolicies/reliance' %>
                </div>

                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="pricing">
                    <%= render 'pages/legalpolicies/pricing' %>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </div>
</div>
```

Both of the above bits of code are in the exact same page of my app. The first one works, the second does not.

How do I get bootstrap tabs working in my app?????

Comment: Any Javascript error shown in your browser console?

Comment: Have you at least checked your console to make sure Bootstrap.js is loading or for any errors? What does your application.js look like?

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

Comment: the js in the bootsnip example i copied over (at the top of the page) works properly.

Answer (score 0):

The *order* and *correct* require-directives should be:

```
1. jquery
2. jquery_ujs
3. bootstrap
4. bootstrap-datepicker
5. tree .
```

Bootstrap seems to use `container-fluid` as class name <s>, the other points look less suspicious to me</s>.

The CSS in the partials should be factored out into the places as suggested by the Rails convention, in order to leverage the asset pipeline and detect possible naming conflicts between your stylesheets and bootstrap's.